# Running buckminster headless from an Eclipse installation

Tags: eclipse, build, headless, buckminster

I got Buckminster installed and it works perfectly within my Eclipse IDE. Now, I'd like to run the headless version of it, but I'm wondering if I have to install the headless version of Buckminster, or if I can launch it from my current, existing, eclipse installation.

Can I specify an eclipse Application or Product after eclipse.exe to trigger Buckminster headless?

Comment: I have two questions: Is there a specific reason you don't want to install Buckminster headless? Are you considering using a build server, such as hudson or jenkins, or do you want to trigger the build using a shell script?

Comment: @MaxHohenegger If i do through shell script is it same as starteppindigo.sh.After buckminster process i get p2 repository.How can i create Eclipse launcher product with this repository.

Comment: @Eshika I am not familiar with "starteppindigo.sh", but in order to create a product you can follow this tutorial here: http://www.ralfebert.de/blog/eclipsercp/rcp_builds/#manual_install

Comment: @MaxHohenegger I have followed this tutorial http://codeandme.blogspot.com/2011/09/buckminster-rcp-build-with-independent.html to create RCP product.But as soon as i import other projects in Eclipse workspace build fails and throws "org.eclipse.core.runtime" Exception.

Comment: @Eshika Superficially this tutorial looks good. I can only recommend the tutorial I posted because I followed it twice, point by point, and it worked for me each time.
If you still have problems, I'd recommend you open a new question, explaining your whole setup in detail with all relevant version numbers etc.
Post the link here and I will have a look.

Comment: @MaxHohenegger I have explained setup in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11499771/buckminster-is-throwing-org-eclipse-core-runtime-coreexception-for-imported-proj .I am using Eclipse Indigo SR2(WIN 32).

Answer (score 1):

I recently wrote new tutorials on Buckminster both for building RCP applications and Xtext projects: http://www.lorenzobettini.it/tag/buckminster/

the examples you find in those blog posts also show some ant files to run Buckminster headlessly.

Answer (score 0):

Buckminster Headless is not an embedded application inside the IDE distribution. It can in fact not be installed in an IDE as it overrides and works around issues with dependencies to the ui bundles.